# Sony Xperia L WiFi and Bluetooth not turning on

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth, sony-xperia, wpa-supplicant

It happened a couple of months ago when I accidentally relocked my bootloader through the Flashtool instead of Backup TA , wifi and bluetooth became inconsistent and kept on crashing the phone.
It sometimes starts to work for a short period of time , but then phone crashes and it doesn't work again for a long time and sometimes on a random reboot it starts again, only to crash the phone. It keeps on showing `Turning WiFi/Bluetooth on...` but it does not turn on.

Here's what all I have tried...

1. Going back to stock ROM and relocking bootloader through restoring TA. (But it didn't help , its worse on stock ROM my phone freezes and I have to go back to custom ROM)
2. I visited the service centre after doing a software repair and relocking it.(They told I might need to replace the motherboard to get it right , its 10 thousand rupees making it senseless option)
3. Tried to look into phone's important files related to wifi and bluetooth to see if something can be done( I don't have enough coding knowledge so I couldn't understand much)

I need help of anyone with knowledge on this topic to kindly help me. I have my TA backup with me. I am ready to provide you with any logs etc. you might need to diagnose the problem.

Also , I have seen some related questions like this but I want a specific solution for a Sony device.And for Android 4.4.4. After reading related questions I think it has to do something with wpa_supplicant files and other module files.

Here is a logcat output:-

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/dalvikvm( 2960): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 11...
E/Term    ( 2960): onCreate
D/Term    ( 2960): TermService started
I/TermService( 2960): Activity called onBind()
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): Local Branch: 
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): Remote Branch: 
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): Local Patches: 
I/Adreno-EGL( 2960): Reconstruct Branch: 
D/OpenGLRenderer( 2960): Enabling debug mode 0
I/Term    ( 2960): Bound to TermService
I/TermService( 2960): Activity binding to service
D/dalvikvm( 2960): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/jackpal.androidterm-1/libjackpal-androidterm4.so 0x41f95c48
D/dalvikvm( 2960): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/jackpal.androidterm-1/libjackpal-androidterm4.so 0x41f95c48
I/libjackpal-androidterm( 2960): JNI_OnLoad
I/Term    ( 2960): waiting for: 2976
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
I/Term    ( 2960): waiting for: 3133
D/dalvikvm( 2960): GC_CONCURRENT freed 616K, 15% free 4143K/4836K, paused 9ms+4ms, total 35ms
W/InputEventReceiver( 2960): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
I/Term    ( 2960): Subprocess exited: 129
W/InputEventReceiver( 2960): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
W/InputEventReceiver( 2960): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm( 2960): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1240K, 22% free 4823K/6140K, paused 3ms+29ms, total 68ms
W/InputEventReceiver( 2960): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
I/Term    ( 2960): waiting for: 5269
I/Term    ( 2960): waiting for: 5284
I/Term    ( 2960): Subprocess exited: 129
I/Term    ( 2960): Subprocess exited: 129
W/InputEventReceiver( 2960): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 2960): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
E/Term    ( 2960): onCreate
D/dalvikvm( 2960): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2139K, 33% free 4669K/6880K, paused 1ms+9ms, total 76ms
I/Term    ( 2960): Bound to TermService
I/TermService( 2960): Activity binding to service
W/InputEventReceiver( 2960): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: It could be useful to have any log files or at least some Warning or Error messages in "logcat"

Comment: Could you please guide me which log files you need? I made a logcat file though but it doesn't state anything about Wifi or Bluetooth.

Comment: just post it to pastebin, for example, and share the link to it here.

Comment: You could focus on the Errors only with the specific filter spec, by doing something like `adb logcat *:E` or Warnings and Errors with `adb logcat *:W`

Comment: to focus specifically on "WIFI", for example, do `adb logcat |grep -C 5 WIFI` on a Linux machine; or maybe `adb logcat |grep -i -C 3 network`.

Comment: I don't have a Linux machine , sorry, can you please guide me if I have a Windows machine or at least show me a online guide page.

Comment: Also there is a copy of what I saw in logcat in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree) and Navigate to `device/system/etc/wifi`

Replace all the files with Sony Xperia L (stock Firmware) ROM's `/system/etc/wifi` files.